# How to put elements in an object array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, object

How to put new elements in an object array in php, I made some code but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
<?php
class DNA{

    private $RSID;
    private $CHROMOSOME;

    public function setRSID($RSID){
        return $this->RSID = $RSID;
    }

    public function setCHROMOSOME($CHROMOSOME){
        return $this->CHROMOSOME = $CHROMOSOME;
    }

    public function getRSID(){
      return $this->RSID;
    }
    public function getCHROMOSOME(){
      return $this->CHROMOSOME;
    }
}

$dna1[] = new DNA;

$dna1[0]->setRSID(1);
$dna1[0]->setCHROMOSOME(2);

$dna1[1]->setRSID(5);
$dna1[1]->setCHROMOSOME(3);

$dna1[2]->setRSID(7);
$dna1[2]->setCHROMOSOME(0);

?>
```

I do not know the correct syntax, I tried to find in the google, but I am not found a good solution.
Someone can help me?

Comment: You should create instance and set it `$dna1[0] = new DNA; $dna1[0]->setRSID(1); $dna1[0]->setCHROMOSOME(2);` for each item of that array

Comment: Most people would probably create the object first, then put it into the array. `$obj = new DNA; $dna[] = $obj;`

Comment: What exactly wanna do? create the object and put the method results in arrays?

Comment: yes. I would like to create array and put values, for exemple: array_push($dna1->setRSID(), 1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you run `new DNA` creates a single object, so if you want to have multiple objects you need to call it multiple times.

In your case, you're just running it once: `$dna1[] = new DNA;` creates a single object, and adds it to an array.

To create three objects, you could do this:

```
// First create an empty array
$dna1 = [];

// Now add objects to it one by one
$dna1[0] = new DNA;
$dna1[0]->setRSID(1);
$dna1[0]->setCHROMOSOME(2);

$dna1[1] = new DNA;
$dna1[1]->setRSID(5);
$dna1[1]->setCHROMOSOME(3);

$dna1[2] = new DNA;
$dna1[2]->setRSID(7);
$dna1[2]->setCHROMOSOME(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Hy you can try with associative array

[php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

The result is like this,

```
$dna = new DNA();
$dna_array[0]['rsid'] = $dna->setRSID(1);
$dna_array[0]['chromsome'] = $dna->setCHROMOSOME(2);

$dna_array[1]['rsid'] = $dna->setRSID(5);
$dna_array[1]['chromsome'] = $dna->setCHROMOSOME(3);

$dna_array[2]['rsid'] = $dna->setRSID(7);
$dna_array[2]['chromsome'] = $dna->setCHROMOSOME(0);

var_dump($dna_array);
var_dump($dna_array[0]);
var_dump($dna_array[1]);
var_dump($dna_array[2]);
var_dump($dna_array);
var_dump($dna_array[0]['rsid']);
var_dump($dna_array[0]['chromsome']);
```